# How to run a .sh script to create a *.zip file?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, sh

I try to write a shell script `create_zip.sh` to zip my desired folders as a .zip file.

The content of `create_zip.sh` is as following:

```
CODE_DIR='exercise_code/'
EXERCISE_ZIP_NAME='exercise_01.zip'
EXERCISE_DIR=$(pwd)

echo 'Zipping file '$EXERCISE_ZIP_NAME
zip -r $EXERCISE_ZIP_NAME $CODE_DIR
echo $EXERCISE_ZIP_NAME ' created successfully!!! '
```

But when I double-clicked on the file `create_zip.sh`, it just opened the Git Bash window and closed immediately. Then nothing happened! (No output message, no newly created *.zip)

How can I solve it? I am using Win10 and with Git Bash as default application to open *.sh file.

Any solution will be very appreciated.

Comment: Open a Git Bash window directly, go to the folder where your script is, and run it from the command line `./create_zip.sh`. It's probably giving an error and the bash window is closing after showing the error since it's "done". My suspicion is that the folder you're trying to zip isn't in the same directory as the script, or Windows is running the script from a default directory that's different from the script's location.

Comment: You might need to add an interpreter shebang line -- add this as the first line of the script `#!/bin/bash`. Also, as @lurker suggests, try running it in the Git Bash window directly, for which you'll need to `chmod 755 create_zip.sh` to make it executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have `zip` installed in Git Bash.
Try the following steps:

1. Navigate to https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zip/3.0/
2. Download zip-3.0-bin.zip
3. In the zipped file, in the bin folder, find
   the file zip.exe
4. Extract the file "zip.exe" to your "mingw64" bin
   folder (for me: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin)
5. Navigate to https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/bzip2/1.0.5/
6. Download bzip2-1.0.5-bin.zip
7. In the zipped file, in the bin folder, find the file bzip2.dll
8. Extract bzip2.dll to your "mingw64" bin folder (same folder - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin)